# Every separable metric space has cardinality less than or equal to the cardinality of the continuum.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

Every separable metric space has cardinality less than or equal to the cardinality of the continuum.

This was stated in my book in a series of questions using the post office metric on $\Bbb R^2$, but I can't think of a way to prove this.

Comment: If $S$ is a countable dense subset of the space, then every element of the space is a limit of a sequence from $S$.

Comment: What @DavidMitra said, plus $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: Could you explain how that shows it can't be greater than the continuum cardinality?  I'm contused as to how that relates.

Comment: Map $x$ to a sequence from $S$ that converges to $x$. This is injective, so the cardinality of your space is at most the cardinality of the set of sequences from $S$. But this is the same as the cardinality of the set of sequences of positive integers.

Comment: Why is the map $x\mapsto (x_n)$ well-defined? In other words, for a fixed $x,$ why can't we have two sequences converging to $x$?

Comment: We are choosing such a sequence for each x, we don't claim that it is unique.