# Compact injective operator and cardinality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be Banach, $T: X\rightarrow X $ compact injective. Then $\#X \leq \#\text{ran}T \leq \#\mathbb{R}$ because compact operators have separable range. Thus, no compact injective operator $X\rightarrow X$ exists if $X$ has cardinality that is greater than the continuum.

Do you have another proof of the fact that there doesn't always exist $T: X\rightarrow X$ compact injective, that doesn't use cardinality?

---

References: [Cardinality of separable metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306597/cardinality-of-separable-metric-spaces) and [Cardinality approach](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359911/existence-of-injective-compact-operators)

Comment: The statement itself involves cardinality. I thus do not understand the question.

Comment: @Jochen right, I made an edit