# Is there a separable and metrisable topological space $X$ so that $\operatorname{card}(x) > {2}^{\aleph_{0} }$?

Tags: general-topology

Is there a separable and metrisable topological space $X$ so that $ \operatorname{card}(X) > {2}^{\aleph_{0} }$?

I can't think of an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cardinality of separable metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306597/cardinality-of-separable-metric-spaces).  Or [Every separable metric space has cardinality less than or equal to the cardinality of the continuum.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843654/every-separable-metric-space-has-cardinality-less-than-or-equal-to-the-cardinali)

Comment: Hint: any point of $X$ is a limit of a sequence from the countable dense subset. How many such sequences are there?